# How to insert a node as root in BST?

Tags: java

We usually insert node in BST as one of internal nodes. I found one C version code to insert it as a root node. The whole process has been divided into 3 steps [Insert node as root](http://adtinfo.org/libavl.html/Root-Insertion-in-a-BST.html#33):

1. Search BST for insertion point
2. Insert new BST node
3. Move BST node to root

I want to write this in java. However, I don't understand how the third step works?

Answer (score 0):

as  [Insert node as root:](http://adtinfo.org/libavl.html/Root-Insertion-in-a-BST.html#33) says:

- If we moved down to the left from a node x during the insertion search, we rotate right at x.
- If we moved down to the right, we rotate left.

in the first picture the **4** is a *right* Node, then we should *rotate left* and reach the second picture, now the **4** is a *left* Node then *rotate right* and reach the third picture and now the **4** is a *right* Node *rotate left* and now **4** is the root, algorithm end.

summary: We can iterate these two principle until move *new Node* to *root*. 

 here is an alternative implementation:

```
class Node{
    Node left,right;
    int val;
    public Node(int val){
        this.val = val;
    }
}

public class BSTDemo {
    public Node insert(Node root,int val){
        Node node = root;
        while(node!=null){
            if(node.val<val){
                if(node.right==null){
                    node.right = new Node(val);
                    return node.right;
                }
                node = node.right;
            }
            else if(node.val>val){
                if(node.left==null){
                    node.left = new Node(val);
                    return node.left;
                }
                node = node.left;
            }
            else{
                return null;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Node rotate(Node root,Node newNode){
        if(root==newNode){
            return root;
        }
        else{
            Node parent = findParent(root,newNode);
            while(parent!=null){
                Node grandParent = findParent(root,parent);
                if(parent.left==newNode){
                    //right rotate
                    parent.left = newNode.right;
                    newNode.right = parent;
                    if(grandParent!=null){
                        if(grandParent.left==parent){
                            grandParent.left = newNode;
                        }
                        else{
                            grandParent.right = newNode;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else{
                    //left rotate
                    parent.right = newNode.left;
                    newNode.left = parent;
                    if(grandParent!=null){
                        if(grandParent.left==parent){
                            grandParent.left = newNode;
                        }
                        else{
                            grandParent.right = newNode;
                        }
                    }
                }
                parent = findParent(root,newNode);
            }
            return newNode;
        }
    }

    private Node findParent(Node root,Node newNode) {
        if(root==newNode){
            return null;
        }

        Node parent = root;
        while(root!=null){
            if(root.val==newNode.val){
                return parent;
            }
            else if(root.val>newNode.val){
                parent = root;
                root = root.left;
            }
            else{
                parent = root;
                root = root.right;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Node root = new Node(1);
        root.right = new Node(5);
        root.right.left = new Node(3);
        root.right.right = new Node(6);
        root.right.left.left = new Node(2);
        BSTDemo bst = new BSTDemo();
        Node node = bst.insert(root, 4);
        root = bst.rotate(root, node);
    }
}
```